# How to add slide in animation when navigating from tab to stack screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

ive got a react navigation structure like so

Home

--RestaurantList

--RestaurantDetails

My Queues

Home and My Queues are within a Tab navigator. RestaurantList and RestaurantDetails are within Home's Stack navigator.

Navigating from RestaurantList to RestaurantDetails gives a slide-in animation because it is navigating from a stack to another stack screen as seen.

https://youtube.com/shorts/VdFyNCwm1yw

I want that same slide in animation for navigating from my My Queues to RestaurantDetails, from a tab screen to a stack screen. It is currently just instant with no animation as seen.

https://youtube.com/shorts/nOZLP9seI14

This is the attached snack used in the videos

https://snack.expo.dev/@meg_hidey/ashamed-celery?platform=web

How can I achieve the same slide-in animation when navigating from MyQueues to RestaurantDetails?